# how to use RegisterHotKey() in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, keyboard, dllimport

I'm trying to register a hot key, I'm translating [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) C++ code into C#:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern
            bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, int vk);
        [DllImport("user32")]
        public static extern
            bool GetMessage(ref Message lpMsg, IntPtr handle, uint mMsgFilterInMain, uint mMsgFilterMax);

        public const int MOD_ALT = 0x0001;
        public const int MOD_CONTROL = 0x0002;
        public const int MOD_SHIFT = 0x004;
        public const int MOD_NOREPEAT = 0x400;
        public const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x312;
        public const int DSIX = 0x36;
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!RegisterHotKey(IntPtr.Zero, 1, MOD_ALT | MOD_NOREPEAT, DSIX))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("failed key register!");
            }

            Message msg = new Message();

            while (!GetMessage(ref msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0))
            {
                if (msg.message == WM_HOTKEY)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("do work..");
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Message
    {
        public int message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

but `RegisterHotKey()` never returns false.
I'm not sure about the arguments passed in the method, IntPtr.Zero should be null, and message class constructor's second argument requires an object. any help is very appreciated!

Comment: see [this](http://bloggablea.wordpress.com/2007/05/01/global-hotkeys-with-net/)

Comment: NOTE: your value for MOD_NOREPEAT is wrong. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Your example works perfectly if you use the proper constant value for MOD_NOREPEAT and the right GetMessage() definition (which return an int and use MSG structure from System.Windows.Interop namespace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

[Hotkey in console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654787/global-hotkey-in-console-application)

Basically, you have to create a "hidden" form to make it work