# How do I use the keydown function on a winform through other windows?

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

I have this piece of code

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode== Keys.Z)
        {
            BarTimer.Value = 0;
            timer1.Start();
            timer1.Interval = 500;
            BarTimer.Minimum = 0;
            BarTimer.Maximum = 80;
        }
    }
```

And it works just fine, but I want to be able to press it when in a fullscreen application, so I can see the progress bar on my second monitor. Is there a property or something i can change to make it work like that?

Comment: Do you mean to respond to the key, when the typing focus isn't in your form, but is in another screen?

Comment: Is the other screen within your application, or can it be in any other application?

Comment: It's a different application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a single key you can use RegisterHotKey.  There is sample code in this answer: [how to use RegisterHotKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911930/how-to-use-registerhotkey-in-c) and the one linked in it.   The Microsoft C++ documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you want to intercept all keyboard input you would need a keyhook.  I suggest you google WH_KEYBOARD_LL and SetWindowsHookEx.  But I don't think you can do this in c#; I've only ever seen key hooks written in C/C++.  They will also cause some firewalls to take an interest - intercepting all keyboard input can be considered potentially hostile.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I know of a nice tutorial I found On code project.
It worked for me when i needed something like this.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook

Regards,