# RegisterHotKey - how to get form instance?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, hotkeys, registerhotkey

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654787/global-hotkey-in-console-application) solution(first answer) to make hotkeys. So, it has event handler method :

```
static void HotKeyManager_HotKeyPressed(object sender, HotKeyEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Hit me!");
}
```

How to get an instance of my form there? I tried making form a static field of class with main method, but I have `System.ArgumentException: Controls created on one thread cannot be parented to a control on a different thread.` How to do it?

Comment: I guess there's something threaded, you need to use `Invoke` if it's the case

Comment: The example you used is only appropriate for a console mode program.  Check this example for a Winforms app, the C# version is further down the page: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/2622427d-1e15-4f30-b01d-57b0ba054f5c/