# Register Hot Keys for C# Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, service

Is there a way to register a Hot Key in Windows service without usage of windows forms. I only found RegisterHotKey C# solutions that include usage of Windows Forms.

Is there any way this could be avoided?

Comment: Check this on SO , They use it in a console application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654787/global-hotkey-in-console-application

Comment: Services now run in a different desktop than the user, so it won't receive the keystrokes.

Comment: Windows Services are generally intended to be run in a non-interactive state.  What are you trying to accomplish?  There may be a different and more suitable approach.

Comment: I am trying to make a simple service that will increase/decrease volume when user hits predefined hot key.