# How do I create a custom C# Console application hotkey

Tags: c#, windows, console, keyboard, hotkeys

I've been working on a system that runs as a console application. But I can't figure out how to create custom hotkeys for it.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>C</kbd> is the `Console.CancelKeyPress`...

I'd like to add a custom hotkey like...

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>S</kbd> and have it run a function that I have in the code.

If anyone got any helpful tips or a basic layout for it please, feel free to reply.

Comment: Maybe you can read this post while you wait another answer :D  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654787/global-hotkey-in-console-application

Comment: Console apps are not suitable for this, there's no mechanism beyond Console.ReadKey().  A global hotkey as shown in Krekkon's link is not equivalent to an application hotkey.  Creating a GUI app in C# isn't very difficult, best way to move ahead.

Comment: Hans Passant : I can't make the application a GUI based one because it'd take too much ram from the computer, application already gets upto 2gb ram when in full spin. It's a server system that has been setup. I need a custom hotkey such as the one i mentioned CTRL - S to save all information gathered on the server so it doesn't get lost when it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi may be this can solve your problem. In my case I use such implementation for hotkey in my app. Class ConsoleKeyInfo is what you need

```
    ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
    do
    {
        cki = Console.ReadKey();
        if ((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0 && cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Z)
        {
            Undo();
        }
        if ((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0 && cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Y)
        {
            Redo();
        }
    } while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```