# Multiple global hotkeys in C# console application

Tags: c#, console-application, global-hotkey

To register global hotkey in console application in C#, I am using the code posted here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3654821/3179989

It works perfectly, but when I add multiple hotkeys, pressing one hotkey will result in running all of the hotkey_pressed events:

```
   HotKeyManager.RegisterHotKey(Keys.E, KeyModifiers.Control);
   HotKeyManager.HotKeyPressed += new EventHandler<HotKeyEventArgs>(HotKeyManager_HotKeyPressed);

   HotKeyManager.RegisterHotKey(Keys.A, KeyModifiers.Control);
   HotKeyManager.HotKeyPressed += new EventHandler<HotKeyEventArgs>(HotKeyManager_HotKeyPressed2);
```

Can somebody help me to change the code, or suggest me any other solution/idea for multiple global hotkeys in c# console.

thanks in advance

Comment: This will not work with the class you are using. Only register one HotKeyPressed-Event. In this event you can check the HotKeyEventArgs with a simple if-statement to determine which of your hotkeys was pressed.

Comment: @user1567896: thanks for your comment. You mean like this? if (e.Modifiers.ToString() + " " + e.Key.ToString()=="Control E") {\\dosomething}
            {

Comment: You don't need to convert the key to string. You can do something like `e.Key == Keys.Enter` and then check ´KeyModifiers´ if the ´control key´ is pressed as well.

Comment: @user1567896 Thank you, How can make this the answer?

Comment: I have posted my comment as an answer below, so you can accept it ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work with the class you are using.

Only register one HotKeyPressed-Event. In this event you can check the `HotKeyEventArgs` with a simple if-statement to determine which of your hotkeys was pressed.