# How to define hot keys using if-else?

Tags: c#, global-hotkey

I want to perform two methods for different pressing of hot keys, checking in if-else what key was pressed

How to do this with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654787/global-hotkey-in-console-application/3654821?noredirect=1#comment82636226_3654821) example?

I use so:

```
private static void Main()
{
  HotKeyManager.RegisterHotKey(key: Keys.G, modifiers: HotKeyEventArgs.KeyModifiers.Alt);
  HotKeyManager.HotKeyPressed += new EventHandler<HotKeyEventArgs>(HotKeyManager_HotKeyPressed);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
private static void HotKeyManager_HotKeyPressed(object sender, HotKeyEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Example HotKeys Activate");
}
```

How do I perform two different events with different HotKeys?

Comment: You have to call RegisterHotKey() more than once.  The HotKeyEventArgs object tells you which specific key was hit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register all your hotkey and then can use the `Key` and `Modifiers` properties of the `HotKeyEventArgs`:

```
private static void Main()
{
    HotKeyManager.RegisterHotKey(key: Keys.G, modifiers: HotKeyEventArgs.KeyModifiers.Alt);
    HotKeyManager.RegisterHotKey(key: Keys.P, modifiers: HotKeyEventArgs.KeyModifiers.Alt);
    HotKeyManager.HotKeyPressed += new EventHandler<HotKeyEventArgs>(HotKeyManager_HotKeyPressed);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
private static void HotKeyManager_HotKeyPressed(object sender, HotKeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Keys.G && e.Modifiers == HotKeyEventArgs.KeyModifiers.Alt)
       OnPressedAltG();
    else if (e.Key == Keys.P && e.Modifiers == HotKeyEventArgs.KeyModifiers.Alt)
       OnPressedAltP();
}

private static void OnPressedAltG()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Alt+G was pressed.");
}
private static void OnPressedAltP()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Alt+P was pressed.");
}
```

Comment: Does not work, I use together with `HotKeyManager.HotKeyPressed += new EventHandler<HotKeyEventArgs>(HotKeyManager_HotKeyPressed);`

Comment: @GooliveR What does "does not work" mean? Note that "A" and "B" are just examples. And the design of this `HotKeyManager` class does not support multiple events, thatswhy I check the currently pressed hotkey in that single event handler.

Comment: @GooliveR updated the answer to better fit your example.