# Using F6 as the global hotkey of an C# console program

Tags: c#, console-application, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I'm using this code to add a global shortcut to my C# console program:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3654821/170931

It works fine with hotkeys like <kbd>Ctrl+F6</kbd>. However, I don't know how to use only <kbd>F6</kbd> as its hotkey. When I use:

```
HotKeyManager.RegisterHotKey(Keys.F6);
```

I got the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter 'modifiers' of
>   'HotKeyManager.RegisterHotKey(Keys,
>   KeyModifiers)'    CALD    C:...\Program.cs   425 Active

Is it possible to use only <kbd>F6</kbd> as the hotkey?

Comment: The method takes two arguments.  The KeyModifiers enum needs to have None = 0 added to make you happy.  Beware that you are not actually going to be happy, you'll make any other program that uses F6 malfunction.  Like VS, etc.

Comment: Can you use `default(KeyModifiers)` as an argument for the `RegisterHotKey()` method?