# Listening on a certain key press and react to it with C# on Windows system

Tags: c#, .net, windows

**Hi, i want to write a farming bot for a certain game.**

What i want to achieve is while playing the game, when i press for example **F1** then the service (console program or a .Net Core Worker Service) should press the button for example **A,B,C** for me. And pressing ESC then the service will stop writing ABC...

This should be happened **on a event driven approach.**

At the moment i just turn off the console Programm..

Pressing A,B,C is already realized with the "User32.Dll" wrapper. But how can i listen to the F1 or ESC event?

How can i do this with C# on Windows?

Comment: refer this for console App- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app & https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/windowsforms/keyboard-handling/how-can-i-catch-keyboard-messages-on-a-application-wide-basis

Comment: @Brijesh Both of those approaches would require the console/application to be in FOCUS to catch the keypress event. If you want to capture keypresses when your app is NOT IN FOCUS, then you can either use a (1) Low Level Keyboard Hook via WK_KEYBOARD_LL, or (2) Register a Hotkey with the system. [Examples of both approaches can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654787/global-hotkey-in-console-application).